# Typed lambda functions in Common Lisp

Tags: function, lambda, common-lisp, clos, generic-function

I don't know of any practical uses for this, it just came to my mind whether there is any thing comparable to `defmethod` to `defun` for `lambda`? Something like this

```
(defmacro tlambda (args &body body)
  (let* ((gf-name (subseq (write-to-string (gensym)) 2))
         (gf-sym (read-from-string gf-name)))
    `(progn (defmethod ,gf-sym ,args ,@body)
        (prog1 (symbol-function ',gf-sym) (unintern ',gf-sym)))))

(tlambda ((x fixnum)))          ;#<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION #:G759 (1)>
(funcall (tlambda ((x fixnum)) (* x 2)) 4) ;8
(funcall (tlambda ((x list)) (second x)) '(a s d f)) ;S
(funcall (tlambda ((x string)) (string-upcase x)) "lambda") ;"LAMBDA"
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that this makes sense in the shape you show.  What should happen if the type doesn't match?  If you just want to check types, use `check-type`.

`Defmethod` and `defun` are not really comparable, by the way.  `Defun` registers a function, while `defmethod` adds a *method* to an existing (though maybe implicitly created) *generic function*.  The types that you use in a method definition are used to *dispatch* (runtime polymorphism) to the right method upon invocation of the generic function.  The mechanisms for this dispatch are a bit expensive when constructed, so you probably shouldn't try to do that on the fly (something like a `generic-lambda`) or transiently (something like a `method-let`).

Instead, use (`e`/`c`)`typecase` and similar for ad hoc dispatch, and `check-type` for checking types.  There are also libraries for pattern-based polymorphism (e. g. optima, trivia), which you could use for more elaborate cases.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Svante that you probably don't want this.  But if you did want it the way you are doing it is very confused: I simply don't understand what you are doing with `gf-sym` and `gf-name` but it represents some quite serious confusion about symbols I think (and is almost certainly unsafe).  Instead you could do something like this:

```
(defmacro tlambda (&body cases)
  (let* ((gf-name (gensym)))
    `(progn
       ,@(mapcar (lambda (case)
                   `(defmethod ,gf-name ,@case))
                 cases)
       (symbol-function ',gf-name))))
```

And now

```
> (let ((l (tlambda
             ((x y) (cons x y))
             ((x (y integer))
              (declare (ignore x)) y))))
    (values (funcall l 'a 'b)
            (funcall l 'a 1)))
(a . b)
1
```

I'm not sure whether the objects created by `tlambda` can be garbage-collected: it may be they can.